# WpAlchemy - _global_head is being output 3 times

Tags: wpalchemy

Today while attempting to make use of the repeating fields function (have_fields_and_multi) I've discovered that with the latest WpAlchemy (1.6.1) and the latest Wordpress (4.6.1), the inline JavaScript blocks from MetaBox.php are output 3 times on the admin page.  This breaks functionality because 3 sets of onclick events are included.

I tried this on two local sites with the same result.

I'm attempting to work around it via event.stopImmediatePropogation as a temporary fix but would love to have something more solid. 
(I have added this as an issue at https://github.com/farinspace/wpalchemy/issues/111 as well)

Am I'm alone in experiencing this problem, and does anyone have any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clue was in the original script here - line 460 of MetaBox.php has the comment "// todo: when first run define a constant to prevent other instances from running again ...". The code below fixed this issue.

```
if(!defined('HEAD_CALLED')):
  add_action( 'admin_head', array( $this, '_global_head' ) );
  define('HEAD_CALLED', true);            
endif;
```